# difference between List<T> and List<T>=new List<T> in c#

Tags: c#

I am sorry if my question is silly, i am new to c#

I want to know what is the exact difference between when we create a List variable like this

```
List<T> lstStudents;
```

and when we create a list like this

```
List<T>= new List<T>();
```

i just found out that even if we create a variable without intializing an object to it, still we would be able to add new objects, if it is so then what is the difference between this two
let me explain the scenario with some code which i was trying

```
 List<Product> product = new List<Product> { 
                                        new Product() { ProductID = 1, ProductName = "A" }
                                        ,  new Product() { ProductID = 2, ProductName = "B" }
                                        ,  new Product() { ProductID = 3, ProductName = "C" }
                                        ,  new Product() { ProductID = 4, ProductName = "D" }
                                        ,  new Product() { ProductID = 5, ProductName = "E" }
                                    };
```

now if i add a variable like this

```
 List<Product> p = product;
```

I am still able to add objects in this variable

```
  p.Add(new Product { ProductID = 3 });
```

Please clarify my doubt.

Thank you

I am sorry may be i am doing something wrong in this code

```
 public class Students
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }      
    }

  List<Product> product = new List<Product> { 
                                        new Product() { ProductID = 1, ProductName = "A" }
                                        ,  new Product() { ProductID = 2, ProductName = "B" }
                                        ,  new Product() { ProductID = 3, ProductName = "C" }
                                        ,  new Product() { ProductID = 4, ProductName = "D" }
                                        ,  new Product() { ProductID = 5, ProductName = "E" }
                                    };


            List<Product> p = product;
            p.Add(new Product { ProductID = 3 });
```

when i run this i get 6 items instead of 5

Comment: the first one doesnt *create* a list at all, it just declares the var and its type. `new` creates/initializes the actual object

Comment: The first one declares a variable of type `List<T>` which is initialized to `null`, assuming the type `T` is defined. The second one is a syntax error.

Comment: There is no sample of "without intializing an object to it, still we would be able to add new objects" in the post - which probably would highlight what "initializing" actually mean for you (likely different from common meaning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> now if i add a variable like this
>
> ```
> List<Product> p = product;
> ```
>
> I am still able to add objects in this variable

Yes, because *the variables are referencing the same list*.  If you look at `p` you will notice that the added item is reflected there as well.

> i just found out that even if we create a variable without intializing an object to it, still we would be able to add new objects

Not true - if you do this:

```
List<T> lstStudents;
```

and try to add something:

```
lstStudents.Add(...);
```

You will get a compiler error if the list declaration is within a method, and a `NullReferenceException` if it a class member because `lstStudents` is not referencing anything (it is a "null" reference).

> when i run this i get 6 items instead of 5

Yes because the list referenced by `product` contained 5 elements, `p` references the same list, and you added one.

Lists are *reference types*, meaning that "copying" the value of one variable to another variable only copies a *reference* to the underlying object.  It's akin to pointers in older languages like C.

Comment: i have just edited my question can you please take a look at it and help me understand a little better
Thank you

Comment: thank you very much for your help... It helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<T> lstStudents;
```

Is null and:

```
List<T> lstStudents = new List<T>();
```

Is an empty list. Example:

```
List<T> lstStudents;
lstStudents.add(new Student("Bob")); // this will throw a null exception

List<T> lstStudents = new List<T>();
lstStudents.add(new Student("Bob")); // this work just fine
```

Also, as mentioned above:

```
List<T>= new List<T>();
```

Is an erroneous syntax due to the fact that you are not assigning a variable name.

Comment: "is null" -- if it is a class member, yes.  For a local variable, it's simply uninitialized, and the compiler won't let you read from it until it is written.

Comment: i have just edited my question can you please take a look at it and help me understand a little better
Thank you

Comment: @MindingData's answer below should clarify this for you. Take note of his explaination on how Lists are reference types. By setting `p` to `product` you are just telling p to point to the same `List` in memory as product. If you modify one you modify the other.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you have 3 different ways of "creating" a list going on.

```
List<T> lstStudents;
```

This creates a list, but it doesn't actually "point" to anything. It is null. If you try and add items to it you will get a null reference exception.

```
List<T> listStudents = new List<T>();
```

This creates a new list in memory. It's empty and you can add items to it as per normal.

```
List<T> list1 = new List<T>() { // Add some items here};
List<T> list2 = list1;
Student newStudent = new Student();
list2.add(newStudent);
list1.Contains(newStudent); // This equals true.
```

Now this is where I think you may be getting confused. A List is a reference variable in C#. That means that two different pointers can point to the same list. In the example above, we've created our first list and added some items. In the next line we've created a second list but "pointed" it to the first list. We then add a new student to the second list, and magically it shows up in the first list? How? It's because the first and second list are actually the same. They just have two different pointers to the same space in memory.

For more reading on Reference types, here is the official MSDN documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

Comment: *This creates a list, but it doesn't actually "point" to anything. It is null. If you try and add items to it you will get a null reference exception.* All wrong, it creates a *placeholder* for a list, it's not even null, if you define it in class level the compiler will change it to behave as if it were assigned a null, but if you create it locally on a function it wouldn't even compile as the compiler will yield an exception because the variable is uninitialized.

Comment: i have just edited my question can you please take a look at it and help me understand a little better
Thank you

Comment: @Gusman "but if you create it locally on a function it wouldn't even compile". Not sure if I'm understanding you correctly. https://dotnetfiddle.net/sOlj6H

Comment: Try to use the variable as you stated on the nullreferenceexception example, it will not compile.

Comment: @Gusman & MindingData
Thank you for your help